# Installing Cython Packages Error: Cannot compile

Tags: python, cython

I am installing `implicit` through git+https://github.com/benfred/implicit.git@f33d2e7d753f3ab4da0901485bd68e47dba7b9eb

And I got this error during installation

```
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'nvidia' compiler
```

I am using tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0-gpu as my docker base image,
image digest: `9a52554e85ae666767c28f9af70e56caa7e6d75325951ab021fbd4bb1447a340`

This error never happened before, I am not sure what happened to the compiler or which compiler should be used?

Please help me, any help or advise are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found this is an issue of python setuptools,
Fix the version of setuptools to 59.8.0 will workaround